# React link this as a state inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have array of records from database.
It's called `data` and I loop through it.
I want to add a `Link` and pass `state` here but I have got

> createBrowserHistory.js:167 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function createHref(location) {
>       return basename + Object(_PathUtils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["createPat...... } could not be cloned.`

my code is

```
{data.map(row => {
  <Link to={{ pathname: `/publisher/${row.id}`, state: { publisher: row, publisher_props: this.props } }} >{row.name}</Link>
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I think you want to use `\`/publisher/${row.id}\`` (with back ticks) instead of `'/publisher/${row.id}'` (with single quotes)

Comment: @PatrickHund i used ` in my code , it's just for code format at SO